# Is there a risk in stopping haystack indexing mid-way?

Tags: indexing, django-haystack

Hi I made the mistake of re-indexing my entire database, 2.6 million COMPLICATED records. Is there a risk in cancelling the indexing midway? I assume the risk might be corruption of the index of the one record getting indexed at the time indexing is cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of trying to fix a broken index, I am going to say yes, there is a risk. I have a massive 300GB database and I finally concluded I have to re-index the whole thing (5 day process). So yes, don't stop indexing half-way. Please upvote.